# Why a single cross compiling doesnt work? Error: bash: ./test1: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I'm using my Ubuntu 14.10 x64 PC to cross compile to run my programs in my Beaglebone Black but I'm getting a strange error when I try to run the compiled program in my BBB.

The command lines bellow show how I'm doing all steps:

- PC:writing the code → compiling with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` → transfering to BBB through `sftp`

  ```
  cleber@cleber:~/test1$ nano ./test1/test1.c

  cleber@cleber:~/test1$ more test1.c
  #include "stdio.h"

  int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world !\n");
    return 0;
  }

  cleber@cleber:~/test1$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test1.c -o test1

  cleber@cleber:~/test1$ file test1
  test1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ee8c02a051254b2acb7b9054e4599a495da26415, not stripped

  cleber@cleber:~/test1$ sftp debian@192.168.7.2
  debian@192.168.7.2's password: 
  Connected to 192.168.7.2.
  sftp> put /home/cleber/test1/* /home/debian/test1
  Uploading /home/cleber/test1/test1 to /home/debian/test1/test1
  /home/cleber/test1/test1                                                                                      100% 8416     8.2KB/s   00:00    
  Uploading /home/cleber/test1/test1.c to /home/debian/test1/test1.c
  /home/cleber/test1/test1.c                                                                                    100%   81     0.1KB/s   00:00    
  sftp> exit
  ```
- Beaglebone / through SSH: (running the compiled code received)

  ```
  debian@beaglebone:~/test1# chmod +x test1

  debian@beaglebone:~/test1$ ls -la
  total 32
  drwxr-xr-x  2 debian debian 4096 Mar  2 01:13 .
  drwxr-xr-x 13 debian debian 4096 Mar  2 01:08 ..
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 debian debian 8416 Mar  2 01:11 test1
  -rw-r--r--  1 debian debian   81 Mar  2 01:11 test1.c

  debian@beaglebone:~/test1$ ./test1
  -bash: ./test1: No such file or directory
  ```
- But when I compile in the BBB it works:

  ```
  debian@beaglebone:~/test1$ gcc test1.c -o test12

  debiandebian@beaglebone:~/test1$ ls -la
  total 32
  drwxr-xr-x  2 debian debian 4096 Mar  2 01:30 .
  drwxr-xr-x 13 debian debian 4096 Mar  2 01:08 ..
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 debian debian 8416 Mar  2 01:11 test1
  -rw-r--r--  1 debian debian   81 Mar  2 01:11 test1.c
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 debian debian 5048 Mar  2 01:30 test12

  debian@beaglebone:~/test1$ ./test12
  Hello world !

  debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/test1$ file test1 test12
  test1:  ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0xa0028cee2a4b255154907bcb499a59e41564a25d, not stripped
  test12: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x6a05d95c39cc59d2d407655778dc2ef6f53f02cd, not stripped

  debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/test1$ ldd test1 test12
  test1:
      not a dynamic executable
  test12:
      libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e1e000)
      /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f15000)
  ```

May this problem is caused because is used a x64 arch to cross compile a 32bits executable? I installed some libs of 32bits but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I even have no idea if it's the correct cause of the problem.

Maybe these informations below are useful:

PC:

```
cleber@cleber:~/test1$ cat /etc/issue.net; uname -ar
Ubuntu 14.10
Linux cleber 3.16.0-44-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 7 02:07:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BBB:

```
cat /etc/issue.net; uname -ar
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone70 #1 SMP Fri Jan 23 02:15:42 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I'm newbie with Linux and I'm stuck in this step and unfortunately i really need to resolve it quite fast :'( I hope to get some help here!

Tks in advanced!

Comment: Could you post `file test1 test12` output  in beagle system?

Comment: There was a related question/answer [in SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24607099/2388257)

Comment: @Sneetsher I edited the question to increment you require. They are equal :'( . Tks for replying!

Comment: @CleberMarques , I'm pretty sure the answer pointed by Hi-Anger will work for you. You can also confirm that by using this command `ldd test1 test12`

Comment: @Hi-Angel I tried to execute by typing `./test1 -static` but I got the same result. I think that if the problem was that, the test12 also would not execute

Comment: @Sneetsher, the result  of  `ldd test1 test12`: 
`test1: not a dynamic executable`
`test12: libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e43000)
 /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f3a000)`

Comment: @CleberMarques , you have to recompile it, `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static test1.c -o test1`

Comment: @Sneetsher, @Hi-Angel, Great! You resolved my problem with terminal but i've the same issue using Eclipse. Probably `-static` would work as well but I've no idea where I've to put `-static` on eclipse. Do you know?

Comment: @CleberMarques, Check Project > Setting > C compiler: options. Please, could you write an answer.

Comment: @CleberMarques, btw, could you recompile the dynamically linked `test1` then copy it to beagle then run `ldd test1 test12`  and post output to the question.  your previous output `test1: not a dynamic executable` test1 was static build. it will help coming people to read about this issue.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I'm not sure if i've done it correct. To recompile the dynamically linked `test1` I type:  
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -dynamic test1.c -o test1`
and after copy to bbb I type: 
`debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/test1$ ldd test1 test12`
`test1: not a dynamic executable`
`test12:  libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6ebe000)
 /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fb5000)`

Is that you asked for?

Comment: @CleberMarques, test1 is still static. delete it then compile without any additional option `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test1.c -o test1`

Comment: @Sneetsher, I did as you said. After delete, recompile and transfer it, the result was a not a dynamic executable. I added this step in the main post in the end of the 3th code. this result seems the an issue, right? would be interesting to fix it? btw, after I'm done with all steps I'll conclude this topic answering my own question to help other people.

Comment: I check mine and it have same behavior. I didn't expect that. May be a default option which we are not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Just compile the code statically:

PC:

```
cleber@cleber:~/test1$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static test1.c -o test1

cleber@cleber:~/test1$ sftp debian@192.168.7.2
debian@192.168.7.2's password: 
Connected to 192.168.7.2.
sftp> put /home/cleber/test1/* /home/debian/test1
Uploading /home/cleber/test1/test1 to /home/debian/test1/test1
/home/cleber/test1/test1                                                                                      100% 8416     8.2KB/s   00:00    
Uploading /home/cleber/test1/test1.c to /home/debian/test1/test1.c
/home/cleber/test1/test1.c                                                                                    100%   81     0.1KB/s   00:00    
sftp> exit
```

BBB:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/test1$ ./test1
Hello world !
```

As you can see, the cross compiled executable `test1` is static:
`test12` was compiled by gcc on BBB just to compare.

```
debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/test1$ ldd test1 test12
test1:
    not a dynamic executable
test12:
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e12000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f09000)

debian@beaglebone:~/Desktop/test1$ file test1 test12
test1:  ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x8d34ee7f6f2798fa153dea185f77443d06b6ab61, not stripped
test12: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x6a05d95c39cc59d2d407655778dc2ef6f53f02cd, not stripped
```

Thanks all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I Had the exactly same issue so i did following

> sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
>
> sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

After this i configure my compilation tools in eclipse to point to the above installed directory and complied the program

After compiling i copy the executable into beagle bone black rev c and executed there through command line and it started working :)